# Why do Multiple Calls to jQuery UI Position Result in Different Placement?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have an odd issue when using jQuery UI to position a div.  Calling the function the first time places the div in the expected location.  Subsequent calls place the div further and further to the right and bottom of the window.  Below is the least amount of code I could reproduce the problem with.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>jQuery UI Position Test </title>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
        #header {
            height: 100px;
            background: orange;
        }

        #content {
            height: 300px;
            background: blue;
        }

        #message {
            width: 300px;
            background: yellow;
            position: absolute;
            display: none;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="header"></div>
    <div id="message">a message to the user</div>
    <div id="content">
        <input id="ShowMessageButton" type="button" value="Show Message" />
    </div>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#ShowMessageButton').bind("click", function () {
                $('#message').position({ my: "center top", at: "center bottom-12", of: "#header" });
                $('#message').fadeIn(800).delay(1000).fadeOut(1000);
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

If you run the code the first time you get this, which is what I expected.

[Screen Shot 1 http://www.michaelware.net/OutsideImages/jQueryPositionIssue/Screen1.png](http://www.michaelware.net/OutsideImages/jQueryPositionIssue/Screen1.png)

After the second call

[Screen Shot 2 http://www.michaelware.net/OutsideImages/jQueryPositionIssue/Screen2.png](http://www.michaelware.net/OutsideImages/jQueryPositionIssue/Screen2.png)

After the third call

[Screen Shot 3 http://www.michaelware.net/OutsideImages/jQueryPositionIssue/Screen3.png](http://www.michaelware.net/OutsideImages/jQueryPositionIssue/Screen3.png)

Please note you have to let the fadein/fadeout finish or the problem will not occur.

Comment: Here's a JSFiddle with the code in for anyone that wants to try it: http://jsfiddle.net/PaDBk/

Comment: and what you expect on subsequent calls

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Two things. First `.bind()` has been deprecated in favor of `.on()`. Second, you need to change the order of your calls to:

```
$('#ShowMessageButton').on("click", function () {
    $('#message').fadeIn(800).position({
        my: "center top",
        at: "center bottom-12",
        of: "#header"
    }).delay(1000).fadeOut(1000);
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/PaDBk/3/)**

As the [docs for position](http://api.jqueryui.com/position/) state, "Note: jQuery UI does not support positioning hidden elements". Since you are trying to use position on a hidden element, you need to make it visible first. You can witness this if you don't totally fade the element out in [**this example**](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/PaDBk/4/) using the format of your original code.

Comment: This gives exactly the behavior I want but I don't understand why.  Does the fadeIn not complete before the position?  In the Fiddle you can clearly see the div fading in after its in the correct position over the header and content areas.

Comment: In your original code, the click triggers a call to position on a hidden element every time, which position can't deal with. If the element isn't completely hidden, it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Try This -

```
$('#message').position({ my: "center top", at: "center bottom-12", of: "#header" });
$('#ShowMessageButton').bind("click", function () {
      $('#message').fadeIn(800).delay(1000).fadeOut(1000);
});
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/PaDBk/1/)